# Why won't my fetch response by passed in my dispatch?

Tags: javascript, express, firebase, redux, fetch

I'm trying to use a node server as the intermediary between firebase and my react native app.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here with my fetch?

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3090/')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
      //dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response.json()});
    });
  };
};
```

this is the node/express router:

```
const router = (app) => {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
      .once('value', snapshot => res.json(snapshot.val()));
  });
};
```

If I `console.log` the `response.json()` then I just get this:

[image]

If I console.log response, I get this:

[image]

How can I get rid of the headers? If I do `console.log(response._bodyInit)` then I get this:

[image]

Which looks like what I need.

But if I pass it through as payload then I get this error:

[image]

My previous action creator directly worked with firebase, like this:

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
      .once('value', snapshot => {
         console.log(snapshot.val())
          dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
       });
    };
};
```

If I `console.log(snapshot.val())`. Then I got this:

[image]

This works just fine and looks the same as the last console.log of `console.log(response._bodyInit)`.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Your first code will result in a Promise resolved to `undefined` - because you don't return anything in the `.then` ... and by the way `response.json()` returns a Promise too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, so you need another link in the Promise chain

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3090/')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: json});
        });
    };
};
```

If you don't need to console.log the json

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3090/')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: json}));
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch works a little different, when you call `response.json()` that returns another promise, so you need to chain another `then` after you return the new promise:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3090/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(aFunctionToDoSomethingWithTheJson);
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful and quick to respond :)